# Bootstrap 4 - Dropdown AND Tooltip on Button?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to specify that a button acts as both a dropdown trigger AND a tooltip source?

I've been able to get it to do one or the other, but not both. My code below works as a dropdown, but if I reposition the `data-toggle="dropdown"` to before the one for tooltip, then it renders a tooltip instead:

```
<button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="dropdown"
            data-placement="bottom"
            title="Test Tooltip">
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can initialize the tooltip through any attribute, id or class to avoid crossover with dropdown.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-toggle-second="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

`$('[data-toggle-second="tooltip"]').tooltip();`

https://www.codeply.com/go/aFEQgHs1sC

Comment: I like this method for its elegance... and it doesn't require an additional click handler to hide the tooltip.

Answer (score 4):

In such cases I find it easiest to simply put the label of the button within a span that has the tooltip itself

```
<button class="btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Test Tooltip">
    Button label
  <span>
</button>
```

This way the button has the toggle action for the click event (including on the label) but the label has the tooltip event, and the two data-toggle attributes are on different elements so don't clash.

Comment: This is discouraged, according to Bootstrap 4 documentation:

"You should only add tooltips to HTML elements that are traditionally keyboard-focusable and interactive (such as links or form controls). Although arbitrary HTML elements (such as <span>s) can be made focusable by adding the tabindex="0" attribute, this will add potentially annoying and confusing tab stops on non-interactive elements for keyboard users. In addition, most assistive technologies currently do not announce the tooltip in this situation."

Comment: @PiDa Interesting... I could argue that the tooltip is still on the button (ie the span is part of the button rather than an arbitrary span elsewhere) but I take your point (and I don't know enough about how assistive technologies operate in practice to comment on the finer details) and so I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making something like this where you have the button as `data-toggle="tooltip"` And add a dropdown

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
 <li class="btn btn-sm dropdown" id="example" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Test Tooltip" >  
   <a id="dropdown" href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Im a drop down with a tooltip <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
       <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Link or whatever</a></li>
     </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

`$('#example').tooltip();`

http://jsfiddle.net/h56xw8wq/67/

Comment: So you’re suggesting a wrapping component? I had thought of that, but the tooltip sticks around and covers the drop down. I have to manually hide it, which is ugly.

Comment: Also- what browser did you use? I'm using Chrome and Firefox, and the fiddle doesn't show a tooltip...

Comment: @theMayer im using Chrome but that shouldnt affect anything in fiddle. I have been testing around with the tooltip but I am not finding a way of having the tooltip not cover the dropdown if the tooltip is at the bottom of the button.

Comment: And sometimes dropdowns actually expand upward, if the window is small or the control is close to the bottom of the page, much to my dismay

Comment: @theMayer I see. Den Potapov his answer is very usefull aswell (I would say better then mine), I would use that.